# Add onclick event to a dynamic created link (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have many links which are dynamically created with PHP and now I want to add an onclick event.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($xyz)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href=\"test.php?parameter=". $row['z'] ."\" target=\_blank>" . $row['z'] . "</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";}
```

but I want like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($xyz) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href=\"test.php?parameter=". $row['z'] ."\" target=\_blank>" . $row['z'] . onclick="test()"</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";}
```

is this possible?

Comment: of course it is possible..what you try?

Comment: I want to set a value from select box in another select box on a page which is open when i click on the link

Comment: there are a ways to handle click event but on simple example is posted below.see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood what exactly you are asking but I try to answer you the same:

You can't record a normal JS variable in a page session and then to access to it after the loading of a page.
For this case you can use cookies (that are accessible via server-side too):

```
// put this code into methods that users suggested you.
document.cookie = "value_selected=something"
```

and once page is loaded:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
var value_selected  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cookies[YOUR_COOKIE].split("=")[0]))
```

or server side:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"test.php?parameter=". $row['z'] ."\" data-something=htmlentities($_COOKIE['value_selected']) target=\_blank>" . $row['z'] . "</a></td>"; //(example)
```

Or more simply, pass the value selected through query

```
?value_selected=something //elaborate the new link in the method users suggested you
```

and

```
in server-side, use $['GET'] to obtain all values in query string.
```

IMHO I think the first choice is simpler than second.

I hope I helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($xyz) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td><a class='myclick' href=\"test.php?parameter=". $row['z'] ."\"   target=\_blank>" . $row['z'] . **onclick="test()"**</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";}
```

i have added a class to link as myclick
and in jquery

```
$(document).on('click','.myclick',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this..just a simple way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function test(){
    alert('test');
 }

</script>
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($xyz) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href='your link' onclick='test()'></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```